# Use the beta variant

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math, greek

Is it possible to use the curled beta: ϐ (U+03D0) in a formula?

There are variants available for `\epsilon`, `\theta`, `\phi`, `\rho`, `\sigma` and `\phi` with `\varepsilon`, `\vartheta`, etc... but there is no `\varbeta`. Why is that?

Comment: It should be noted that DeTeXify does not produce a result for a decently accurate rendition of this symbol, and it is not included in [`symbols-a4`](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: There is a `ϐ` and a `ϰ` at least in MinionPro (and probably MyriadPro).

Comment: There is no variant beta in the standard Computer Modern fonts. I know of no TeX math font providing it. Some OpenType ones do; for usage with `unicode-math` Asana Math, Latin Modern Math and XITS Math.

Comment: I'd add that usage of `\varphi` and `\phi` with different meanings is disputable; the same for the other pairs. They are just stylistic variants.

Comment: @egreg They are stylistic variants but they are used with different meanings (sometimes): `\varphi` is the usual phi, a variable; `\phi` is usually the 1.618… number; `\varphi` is usually used in polar spheric coordinates while `\phi` is usually seen in cylindricals. Also I've seen `\epsilon` for Levi-Civita and `\varepsilon` for everything else. The case of `\vartheta` is different (at least from what I've seen), some people prefer to use one or another, not both of them in the same document.

Comment: @egreg: Math fonts from the MinionPro package do have `\varbeta` and `varkappa`.

Comment: @Bernard Good to know. Of course this requires changing the text fonts to Minion.

Comment: Of course! Personally I prefer Minion Pro to Computer Modern. My dream would be to have a Sabon math font!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can with XeLaTeX and the [`mathspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathspec) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmathfont(Greek){Cambria Math}

\begin{document}
$\alpha^2 + \varbeta^2 =\gamma^2$
\end{document}
```

[image: sample code output]

Here `Cambria Math` can be replaced by any font on your filesystem that supports this character.  Fileformat.info has a [list of all known fonts supporting it](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3d0/fontsupport.htm) and a [list of locally installed fonts that support it](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm?text=%CF%90%20-%20GREEK%20BETA%20SYMBOL%20%28U%2B03D0%29).

As egreg notes, you can also do it with the [`unicode-math`](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) package:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[math-style=TeX]{Cambria Math}
\newcommand{\varbeta}{ϐ}
\begin{document}
$\alpha^2 + \varbeta^2 =\gamma^2$
\end{document}
```

Comment: `mathspec` is not compatible with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Oops! I assumed it was since fontspec is.  I've edited.

Comment: As far as I know, Cambria Math is suitable for usage with `unicode-math`; `mathspec` is mostly a collection of hacks, not really recommended for math intensive documents.

Comment: @egreg: Good to know.  I've been using mathspec for years and run into some bugs but I didn't realize it wasn't ready for prime time.  I've included a unicode-math implementation.

Comment: Thanks. Too bad Computer Modern doesn't support it, I'm allergic to Cambria. I'll try with Arial or Minion Pro

Answer (score 5):

With the MinionPro package.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\begin{document}
$\epsilon\varepsilon\phi\varphi\theta\vartheta\kappa\varkappa\varbeta\beta$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**1.** Go to [this side](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm?text=%CF%90%20-%20GREEK%20BETA%20SYMBOL%20%28U%2B03D0%29) and check which fonts on your system provide this symbol.

**2.** Try including them like below and choose the one, you like most:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
Asana Math:
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
$\symbol{"003D0}$

XITS Math:
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
$\symbol{"003D0}$

Linux Libertine O:
\setmathfont{Linux Libertine O}
$\symbol{"003D0}$

FreeMono:
\setmathfont{FreeMono}
$\symbol{"003D0}$

FreeSerif:
\setmathfont{FreeSerif}
$\symbol{"003D0}$

DejaVu Serif:
\setmathfont{DejaVu Serif}
$\symbol{"003D0}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**3.** Define the symbol in the font you liked most and use it e.g. like this:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range="03D0]{XITS Math}

%\show\varbeta
\newcommand{\varbeta}{\ensuremath{\symbol{"03D0}}}

\begin{document}
In the next formula I will use \verb+\varbeta+ which yields \varbeta{} in text, inline math ($\varbeta \neq \beta$) and display math
\begin{align*}
\varbeta + \vartheta &= \varepsilon\\
\beta + \theta &= \epsilon
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is straightforward, but after picking the symbol from other font you need to load another `range=…` from the original font, so that all the dimensions are taken correctly, here, for instance `\setmathfont[range=\sum]{Latin Modern Math}`.

Comment: This is really not that cool. Will think about that when I have time. For `\setmainfont{}` in `fontspec` it's possible to do that locally. Why not here? Maybe I do a feature request.

Comment: Step 2 doesn't seem that necessary since the link at Step 1 shows the beta in each of the locally installed fonts.

Answer (score 3):

You can have them with the `MinionPro` package, and `(PDF)LaTeX` both in usual and in French style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{MinionPro}

\begin{document}

  \[ \varbeta^{2} +  \varkappa^{2}  = \upvarbeta^{2} +  \upvarkappa^{2} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same is probably true with `MyriadPro`. Not tested, though, as it requires some job from the user. One has to make the pfb's and the tfm's from the Opentype fonts that come with Adobe Reader.